# Twitter button on ExtJS component

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, twitter, share

I have an ExtJS component and I want to add a twitter button on it;This component is an item for a simple panel.

Here is my code:

```
{
xtype:'container',
id:'tweet-button'
html:'<div><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"' +
     'data-url="http://myPage.com" data-text="newpage" data-via="myTwitterAccount"'+ 
     'data-size="large">Tweet</a>' +
     '<script>!function(d,s,id){' +
     'var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];'+
     'if(!d.getElementById(id)){'+
          'js=d.createElement(s);'+
          'js.id=id;'+
          'js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";'+
          'fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);'+
     '}'+
    '}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></div>'
}
```

The Twitter button seems to be working, the only that is missing is the rendering;Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example to integrate twitter button  -

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        layout:'anchor',
        items:[{
    xtype:'panel',
    height: 700,
    width: 700,
    id:'tweet-button',
    html:'<div><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"' +
         'data-url="http://myPage.com" data-text="newpage" data-via="myTwitterAccount"'+ 
         'data-size="large">Tweet</a></div>' 
    }]
    }); 
});

!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question.The thing is...the code was correct in my source file,I skipped that '+' when I was trying to format the code.

Comment: on the container with the specific html code, which is going to be added on simple ExtJS panel, among other components.